# Made correct merge X into Y, but executed Y into X

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I merged two branches, X into Y, and logs shows so as well, but it executed Y into X, and I am confused.

I am working on a reverting, but I want to know what happened so I dont do it again.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14lq.jpg

2 images 
1: as you can see from the PR log, I merged jesper-ego INTO mikkel-3
2: jesper-ego has file changes from mikkel-3!

I expected mikkel-3 to be updated with the changes from jesper-ego, but I go the opposite

exact steps:

1. Git pull
2. git status -> origin/mikkel (my working branch)
3. git add ., git commit, git push (mikkel->mikkel)
4. on github: new branch via pull request -> mikkel -> mikkel-3
5. new pull request: jesper-ego INTO mikkel-3
6. resolved a single merge conflict (1 import line) via githubs tool
7. confirm PR
8. panic

full logs

```
PS C:\Users\SolutionTeam\Documents\coding\sharepoint\react\st-bmp> git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Already up to date.
On branch mikkel
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/mikkel'.
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   src/webparts/stBmp/database.ts
        modified:   src/webparts/stBmp/models/agendapoint/agendapoint.ts
        modified:   src/webparts/stBmp/models/agendapoint/interfaces.ts
        modified:   src/webparts/stBmp/models/meeting/meeting.ts
        modified:   src/webparts/stBmp/views/ViewMeeting.tsx

...
```

https://pastebin.com/QcRaKNZv

Comment: What are the exact steps which you took, and can you add this information to your question?

Comment: added to post :)

Answer (score 0):

There are *two* merges here :

First, `jesper-ego` into `mikkel-3`, commit 0576ab7.

Then `mikkel-3` into `jesper-ego`, commit 66c793e.

Didn't you make both operations in a row, maybe by mistake?

Comment: I posted logs that I luckily copied...*

I dont see how I could commit anything to jesper-ego, I never checked out that branch. I made changes in a file on my own branch, which I assume caused the merge conflict, but the problem wasnt that, it was the reversal of merging! :/